# Android rotationY value

Tags: android

I want to rotate one view(just like one book).
Code like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:rotationY="30" >

     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bookIcon"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_book_large" />
     <View
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bookIcon"
            android:background="#232323"
            android:rotationY="-90" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

"View"---is used as book's side
"ImageView"---is used as book's icon

I want to make a selected effect when i select one book.The effect is the book rotate 30 degree to the right.As i setted "rotationY" value,i can't see "View"(left side).
I don't know what's the reason.

Thanks in advanced.